# How i remove specific script from header?

Tags: plugins, filters

I need to remove a specific line from the header when opening the site. How do I do this using a filter?

```
<script src="url" data-pn-plugin-url="www.site.com/folder" data-pn-wp-plugin-version="1.0.0" type="text/javascript" async>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script looks like it is coming from some plugin. You'll need to dig into the plugin files to see how the script is added. If it is enqueued, then you can use [wp_dequeue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/). If it is added with an action (e.g. function that echoes the tag to wp_head), then use [remove_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/).